# En Delphi XE ¿cómo puedo modificar Version Info por línea de comandos?

Tags: delphi

Tengo un sistema que tiene varios ejecutables los cuales puedo compilar, para generar un instalador, usando [Final Builder](https://www.finalbuilder.com/), pero no logro modificar la versión de cada ejecutable sin entrar con el IDE, modificarlo desde Opciones del Proyecto y compilando.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con un .bat o de otra forma?

Me imagino que sería tocando los archivos .dproj ya que, básicamente, son archivos xml, pero quería saber si existía una forma de modificarlo sin hacer aparte un editor xml.

Las etiquetas básicas son VersionInfo y VersionInfoKeys.

### Edición:

Directamente con el **Final Builder** lo pude hacer con las acciones *PropertySet define* y *PropertySet assign properties*, en el primero se define la variable que contendrá los valores y cuales de ellos nos interesa (CompanyName, FileVersionString, ProductVersion, etc) y en el segundo se asiga cada valor, si es desde una variable (hay que definirlas previamente) se usa el símbolo porcentaje:

```
BuildVersion - %Version_Build%
MajorVersion - %Version_Major%
```

Para obtener los valores utilizo previamente la acción "Enhanced Prompt for Variables". Luego al compilar cada proyecto (con la acción Build Delphi Win32 Project) marco que tome todos los valores del proyecto salvo Version Info que hago que lo tome de la variable definida en "PropertySet define".

Espero que esto le sirva a alguien más... igual sería interesante saber como modificar los valores por código...

Answer (score 1):

Yo en alguna ocasión lo he hecho utilizando un fichero de recursos.

De esta forma es más fácil controlar la información de versión cuando la generación de la versión está automatizada (en mi caso era utilizando unos ficheros BAT/CMD).

1) Debes desactivar en el fichero **.dproj** la información de debug:

```
<VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>false</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
```

2) Creas un fichero con extensión **.RC** para almacenar la información de versión como recurso:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 3,0,0,8
PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,0,8
FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
  FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
  FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
FILEOS 0x4L
FILETYPE 0x1L
FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
   BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
   BEGIN
      BLOCK "080904e4"
      BEGIN
         VALUE "CompanyName", "My compañía"
         VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.0.8"
         VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.0.8"
         VALUE "InternalName", "Mi nombre Interno"
         VALUE "OriginalFilename", "Testeando.exe"
         VALUE "ProductName", "Mi nombre de producto"
         VALUE "FileDescription", "Descripcion del producto"
         VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Mi compañía"
      END
    END
   BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
   BEGIN
      VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1252
   END
END
```

3) compilar el fichero **.RC** para generar un fichero **.RES** con la siguiente línea:

```
> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin\brcc32.EXE" versioninfo.rc
```

Con esto obtendremos un fichero **versioninfo.rc**

4) Añadir el recurso a nuestro proyecto con la directiva:

```
{$R VersionInfo.res}
```

Una vez que generamos el **EXE**, podemos ver que incluye la información correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.